# SQL: Compare if string is MD5 hash?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, case-sensitive

Question:

I need to COMPARE if a string is a MD5 Hash in SQL.

I found this PHP-function:

```
function isValidMd5($md5)
{
    return !empty($md5) && preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/', $md5);
}
```

Since SQL lacks the {32} syntax, I just duplicate [a-f0-9] 32 times:

```
IF '200ceb26807d6bf99fd6f4f0d1ca54d4' LIKE '[a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9]' 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'YES'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'NO'
END
```

However, to avoid a possible collision with a username consisting of 32 [a-f], however unlikely, I want to do the like comparison uppercase.

But if for testing purposes I do:

```
IF 'E' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS  LIKE ('[a-f0-9]' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'yes'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'no'
END
```

I get yes, and not no. 
However COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS should make it case-sensitive...

How can a make the LIKE in this IF case-sensitive ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to invert the check and make it simpler to maintain by checking for any single thing that will make it fail. This means you don't have to repeat `[0-9a-f]` 32 times in the code.

```
IF LEN(@myValue) <> 32 OR LOWER(@myValue) LIKE '%[^0-9a-f]%' 
BEGIN
   -- No it isn't
END ELSE BEGIN
   -- Yes it is
END
```

i.e., if it's not 32 chars OR it contains a character outside the hexadecimal set then it fails.

Comment: Invert (i.e., match any character that *isn't* 0-9a-f). So it will match 'z' for example. Also, I've just edited my answer as the LIKE pattern needed a small tweak: it's now been wrapped in '%' matches.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Sorry, my fault, I didn't see the changed switching in the if. Yes, this is smarter, from the typist perspective. But it still has the case-sensitivity problem, which is the point of this post.

Comment: No it doesn't - I've used LOWER() to make it case insensitive. Why do you think otherwise? I've seen you state this: "However, to avoid a possible collision with a username consisting of 32 [a-f], however unlikely, I want to do the like comparison uppercase.", but I'm not entirely certain where this comes from? Maybe some context would help...

Comment: But Chris, I want it case-sensitive, that's the point of the entire post. It would be good if it was case sensitive. Removing the lower doesn't make it case-sensitive, however.

Answer (score 2):

Will this work?

```
IF myValue LIKE '[a-f0-9][...]' 
and LOWER(myValue) = myValue
```

Comment: Great, this works (idea wise). I use upper instead. But you miss COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS after myValue

Comment: The problem seems to be the a-f, if I replace it with abcdef, then it works fine. I think the word of the day is: Microsoft's BUG !!!

Answer (score 1):

OK, after painstaking examination of the problem, this is the best solution:

Note that it's important to write ABCDEF instead of A-F, because else any letter in between A and F is not case-sensitive.

(as for A-F: note that little 'a' is a border-case, as it isn't in this range, unlike little 'b'.)

```
DECLARE @myValue varchar(100)

--SET @myValue = '66B9E31D4C59D3802279515F9B1A6222'
SET @myValue   = '66B9E31D4C59D3802279515F9B1B6222'


IF LEN(@myValue) <> 32 OR @myValue LIKE '%[^0-9ABCDEF]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS   
BEGIN 
   print 'No it isn''t'
END ELSE BEGIN 
   print 'Yes it is '
END
```

And as MD5-Checkfunction:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fn_IsMd5Hash]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_IsMd5Hash]
GO




-- ========================================================================
-- Author:  
-- Create date:   26.04.2012
-- Last modified: 26.04.2012
-- Description:   Überprüfen ob string ein MD5-Hash ist
-- ========================================================================

-- PRE:  varchar(50) 
-- POST: True/False 
-- PRINT dbo.[fn_IsMd5Hash]('66B9E31D4C59D3802279515F9B1B6222') 
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].fn_IsMd5Hash(@strInputAnything varchar(50)) 
    RETURNS bit 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @bIsMd5Hash AS bit 

    SET @bIsMd5Hash = 'false' 

    IF LEN(@strInputAnything) = 32 AND NOT @strInputAnything LIKE '%[^0-9ABCDEF]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS 
        SET @bIsMd5Hash = 'true' 

    RETURN @bIsMd5Hash 
END


GO
```

Comment: You need to handle `NULL` also. it returns true. (+1 anyway)

Comment: @zig: If strInputAnything is NULL, it returns false. What do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry. you are correct. my test was incorrect. I tested the first expression you posted, not the function.